# Print blob names in Pycaffe

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I can print blob names in C++ as follow.

```
    for (int index = 0; index < net_->blobs().size(); ++index) //net_->layer_names().size()       
    {     
            const boost::shared_ptr<Blob<float> > blob = net_->blob_by_name(net_->blob_names()[index]);
            int batch_size = blob->num();            
            int dim_features = blob->count() / batch_size;
                std::cout << "Blob name:" << "'" <<net_->blob_names()[index] << "'" << " batch size " << "'" << batch_size << "'" << " channels:" << "'" << blob->channels() << "'" << " height:" << "'" << blob->height() <<  "'" << " width:" << "'" << blob->width() << "'" <<std::endl;
    }
```

I am looking for similar api in python.
I know only to print layer names in python, how to print blob names and size?

```
This is for printing layer names
for layer_name, blob in net.blobs.iteritems():
        print layer_name + '\t' + str(blob.data.shape)
```

Comment: you can print blob names as a list using  `print list(net._blob_names)`

Comment: Your python code actually prints blob names and shape, not layer names.

Comment: Yes, now it can print like "for blob_name, blob in net.blobs.iteritems():"
     "print blob_name + '\t' + str(blob.data.shape)"